# Scheduling camel route for google-pubsub component

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, integration, spring-camel

Apache Camel CronScheduledRoutePolicy not stopping route?

I am trying to start and stop my route which reads from google-pubsub component and pushes to a JDBC datasource(oracle). I want to do this only in certain times of day as the Oracle database would be down from say 10pm-12AM every night during which times I don't want my route to keep processing incoming pubsub messages and want it to stop. But when I try it the route at stop time says:

'{"severity":"WARN","message":"o.a.c.r.q.ScheduledRoutePolicy | Route is not in a started/suspended state and cannot be stopped. The current route state is Stopped"}'

```
@Override
    public void configure() {
        CronScheduledRoutePolicy routePolicy = new CronScheduledRoutePolicy();
        routePolicy.setRouteStartTime("0 15 00 * * ?");
        routePolicy.setRouteStopTime("0 00 22 * * ?");
        System.out.println("am here!!");
        onException(Exception.class)
                .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR," Error processing message: ${header['CamelGooglePubsub.MessageId']} : ${exception}" )
                .to("log:app_error.log?level=DEBUG&showAll=true&showException=true")
                .markRollbackOnlyLast()
                .end();



        CamelContext camelContext= getContext();
        System.out.println("Route Status is" + camelContext.getRouteStatus("{{routeID}"));
        from("google-pubsub:{{google_project_name}}:{{google_pubsub_subscription}}"+
                "?concurrentConsumers={{concurrent_consumers}}"+
                "&maxMessagesPerPoll={{max_messages_per_poll}}"+
                "&connectionFactory=#googlePubsubConnectionFactory")
                .routeId("{{routeID}")
                .routePolicy(startPolicy)
                .noAutoStartup()
```

I wanted the route to start at say 12:15 am (routePolicy.setRouteStartTime("0 15 00 * * ?");

and end at 
routePolicy.setRouteStartTime("0 00 22 * * ?");

Am I doing this right, or should use process() on the route to stop it forcefully, how can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: The WARN just seems to be saying that the route is already stopped. So wont it start the route at the start time? And in other words, does it not work? And what Camel version do you use?

Comment: I am on version 2.23.1. I was expecting the route to stop and my Srping Boot app to terminate, there by allowing my Docker container to be removed. But I see that the Spring Boot app doesn't terminate after my scheduled stop time. Is there a way for me to terminate the route and not just suspend it. Thank you

Comment: This policy will not terminate the JVM, the JVM keeps running. You need to build you own policy if you want to terminate the JVM. If you use something like Kubernetes it has scheduled jobs you can use to setup CRON for when to run containers.

Comment: "By build your own policy" do you mean extend the class and customize it? Kubernetes scheduling doesn't work for me either as the K8s keeps putting in new pods as the current ones don't terminate or exit. Do you know if K8s scheduler can remove a running route even if it hasn't exited the JVM? Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 0):

After going through the command, I think it more like a spring boot question instead of a camel question.

I don't think using the camel cron component can do the job. You may consider to call a service from outside to shutdown the whole spring boot application by running the cron script to send shutdown command to the spring boot application from your docker image.

Here is [an example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown) that you can take a reference.